# Segfault with snprintf (unless I redefine the value the same way just before)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

First of all please excuse me, I can't reproduce the problem, it comes from a big project and when I recover the functions one by one in a more minimalist file it suddenly works (without modifying almost anything) and I can't understand where it can come from.

First of all the project contains these structures:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t x, y;
    uint16_t w, h;
    char* str;
} Text;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t last_tick;
    uint32_t delta_ms;
    float delta;
    float t_fps;
    uint16_t fps;
} Clock;
```

I initialize the `Text` structure which is present in another structure that I will call `Other` from an initialization function for `Other` like this:

```
other->text_frame_rate = (Text){ 0,0,0,0, (char[8]){} };
```

It is supposed to contain text that looks like this `FPS: 60`.

Then I use `snprintf` to write the desired text to it in another function, like this:

```
void _render_frame_rate(Other* other, Clock clock)
{
    snprintf(other->text_frame_rate.str, 8, "FPS: %d", clock->fps);

    ...
}
```

This `_render_frame_rate` function is itself called from another function which looks like this at the parameter level `void Render_game(SDL_Renderer* renderer, Other* other, Clock* clock);`

But I get a segfault unless I redefine the frame again in `_render_frame_rate` like this:

```
void _render_frame_rate(Other* other, Clock clock)
{
    other->text_frame_rate = (Text){ 0,0,0,0, (char[8]){} }; // redefine and no problem

    snprintf(other->text_frame_rate.str, 8, "FPS: %d", clock->fps);

    ...
}
```

And in this case, where the struct `Text` has been redefined it finally works.

I also checked with a `printf("%p\n");` if the address of the pointer was always the same at initialization and at the display function and yes it remains the same.

I also specify that at no time is the `text_frame_rate` value used or modified elsewhere.

What do you think could be causing this behavior?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @IanAbbott's hint I was able to solve the problem by dynamically allocating `text_frame_rate` like this:

```
other->text_frame_rate = (Text){ 0,0,0,0, NULL };
other->text_frame_rate.str = malloc(8);
```

Comment: The lifetime of the `char[8]` pointed to by `other->text_frame_rate.str` will end when control reaches the end of its enclosing block. Perhaps it is still being used after it is dead?

Comment: @IanAbbott Oh yes that's probably it, I didn't think it would happen in a struct (I'm still a beginner), the problem could be solved by a dynamic allocation? (I just tried it and it works, thank you for your comment!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one erroneous example:

```
void init_other_text_frame_rate(Other *other)
{
    other->text_frame_rate = (Text){0, 0, 0, 0, (char[8]){0}};
}

void render_frame_rate(Other* other, Clock clock)
{
    snprintf(other->text_frame_rate.str, 8, "FPS: %d", clock->fps);
}

void foo(Other* other, Clock clock)
{
    init_other_text_frame_rate(other, clock);
    render_frame_rate(other, clock); // invalid!
}
```

The lifetime of the array of `char` pointed to by `other->text_frame_rate.str` expired when `init_other_text_frame_rate(other, clock);` returned to `foo`, so its use in the call to `snprintf` is invalid.